# Problem ssh connection Macbook as host to Debian VirtualBox

Tags: macos, ssh, debian, virtualbox

I meet some problem while connected thru ssh to a Debian Virtualbox from a MacBook Pro.
I success to connect in ssh but some commands don't work from Macbook terminal and I don't understand why.

For example `halt -p` or `a2ensite` works directly on the VirtualBox screen but not thru ssh connection from MacBook terminal.

Is it related to the fact that Debian use bash and Macbook use zsh ?
I think I miss something here.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The shell doesn't matter, but we have not enough information to help. Your command are privileged commands (run as root). Do you have an error? Are you sure you are connected to the expected virtualbox?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. I will be very interested if someone can explain to me why.
But after change zsh to bash on my MacBook:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Then restarting my laptop.
I started the VirtualBox and connect to it in ssh.
And all commands are now working.

Comment: So, you should check .bashrc and .zshrc (and ev. the profile files): probably in bash you set up some environment variables which are essential for Doker.

Comment: I think you are true. However I don't use Docker in that case.